# railo-context/admin/web.cfm missing css in railo deployed in resin

Tags: java, railo, cfml, resin

I have deployed the railo war file in a resin appserver and after deployment the jvm log shows

```
railo-server-root:/var/resin/webapps/railo-4.2.1.008/WEB-INF/lib/railo-server
===================================================================
SERVER CONTEXT
-------------------------------------------------------------------
- config:/var/resin/webapps/railo-4.2.1.008/WEB-INF/lib/railo-server/context
- loader-version:4.3
===================================================================


===================================================================
WEB CONTEXT (3ccbecdfdd85a2c229a64e875ca4821a)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
- config:/var/resin/webapps/railo-4.2.1.008/WEB-INF/railo
- webroot:/var/resin/webapps/railo-4.2.1.008/
- hash:3ccbecdfdd85a2c229a64e875ca4821a
- label:3ccbecdfdd85a2c229a64e875ca4821a
===================================================================
```

I can access a test index.cfm page kept at /var/resin/webapps/railo-4.2.1.008/index.cfm by calling 
    http://domain.com:8080/railo/index.cfm

But when I try to access http://domain.com:8080/railo/railo-context/admin/server.cfm or http://domain.com:8080/railo/railo-context/admin/web.cfm . It is loading a page with no css etc .

I also see the following error in the log
    Wed Nov 19 02:15:51 EST 2014-311 class           railo.runtime.instrumentation.Agent.getInstrumentation() is not returning a Instrumentation
    static resource /railo-context/res/css/admin42.css.cfm was not found @     /var/resin/webapps/railo-4.2.1.008/-context/res/css/admin42.css
    static resource /railo-context/res/css/admin42.css.cfm was not found @    /var/resin/webapps/railo-4.2.1.008/-context/res/css/admin42.css
    static resource /railo-context/res/css/admin42.css.cfm was not found @ /var/resin/webapps/railo-4.2.1.008/-context/res/css/admin42.css

What am I doing wrong

Comment: Can you provide the exact URL getting hit that's returning an error?  If you don't get an answer here, you might try asking on the Railo Google Group. https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/railo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your URL domain.com:8080/railo/railo-context/... is the first railo the context path?  Basically, did you deploy a Railo war but not in the / context?

If so, you might need to modify the /railo-context/ virtual mapping in your railo-server.xml file to map to "/railo/railo-context/"

Also, check any rewrite rules set up.

Comment: Deploying to the ROOT (/) context fixed the error and I can now access it correctly via http://domain.com:8080/railo-context/admin/server.cfm

Answer (score 0):

Railo (not sure which version, but one of the 4.x ones) moved the admin resources (i.e. css, images) out of the same folder as the rest of the admin, meaning they're no longer in `/railo-context/`, and they now use paths like `../res/bar.css` to load them.

Our fix was to add a proxy/rewrite for that other directory, too. For example:

```
ProxyPassMatch  ^/my-secret-railo-location/admin/(.*)$ ajp://localhost:8009/railo-context/admin/$1
ProxyPassMatch  ^/my-secret-railo-location/res/(.*)$ ajp://localhost:8009/railo-context/res/$1
```

Comment: I can see the link etc from the page src as <link rel="stylesheet" href="../res/css/admin42.css.cfm" type="text/css"> . But since I am not using apache not sure if the rules above would help.